# jQuery Mobile w/ Backbone.js JQM initializePage() function not working as expected

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I am working through a simple project trying to learn jQuery Mobile and Backbone.js and am running into an issue. The project is a simple note taking application that saves the notes using HTML5 local storage.

The program is creating pages on the client side and I am attempting to use $.mobile.initializePage() to get the resulting pages to work as expected with JQM. What happens instead is that initializePage() never completes and the resulting loading spinner never goes away.

I have checked the HTML created on the client side and everything is correct as far as I can tell. I have also tried using trigger('create') and createPage() from the console in chrome to see if the pages just aren't being created but that does not fix the issue. No errors are thrown by this and I have not been able to track down a solution to this over the last 2 days. My code is as follows.

HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Local Notes</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.css" media="screen" title="jquery mobile" charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Home Page -->
    <div id="home" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Local Notes</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <a href="#new" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" data-role="button" data-icon="plus" data-theme="b">New</a>
            <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
                <li><a href="#all">All Notes</a></li>
                <li><a href="#nearest">Nearest Notes</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- New Note Form-->
    <div id="new" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>New Note</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="title">Title</label>
                    <input id="title" name="title" value="" />
                </div>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <label for="body">Body</label>
                    <textarea id="body" name="body" value=""></textarea>
                </div>
                <button data-icon="check" data-theme="b">Save</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List of Notes -->
    <div id="all" data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1>All Notes</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul data-role="listview" id="all_notes">
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- List of Note detail pages -->
    <div id="note-detail-list"></div>   

    <!-- Note list template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="note-list-item-template">
        <a href="#note_<%= note.id %>"><%= note.get('title') %></a>
    </script>

    <!-- Note detail template -->
    <script type="text/template" id="note-detail-template">
        <div data-role="header">
            <a href="#home" data-role="button" data-icon="arrow-l" data-rel="back">Back</a>
            <h1><%= note.get('title') %></h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content"><%= note.get('body') %></div>
    </script>

    <script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/underscore.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.js"></script>
    <script src="js/backbone.localStorage.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/application.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var NotesApp = (function(){

var App = {
    stores: {},
    views:{},
    collections:{}
}

// Initialize localStorage Data Store
App.stores.notes = new Store('notes');

// Note model
var Note = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // Use localStorage datastore
    localStorage: App.stores.notes,

    initialize: function(){
        if(!this.get('title')){
            this.set({title: "Note @ " + Date() })
        };

        if(!this.get('body')){
            this.set({body: "No Content"})
        };
    }
})

// Collections
var NoteList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    // This collection is composed of Note objects
    model: Note,

    // Set the localStorage datastore
    localStorage: App.stores.notes,

    initialize: function(){
        var collection = this;

        this.localStorage.bind('update', function(){
            collection.fetch();
        })
    }
})

// Views
var NewFormView = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        "submit form": "createNote"
    },

    createNote: function(e){
        var attrs = this.getAttributes(),
        note = new Note();

        note.set(attrs);
        note.save();

        // Stop browser from actually submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // Stop jQuery mobile from doing its form magic
        e.stopPropagation();

        // Close dialog
        $('.ui-dialog').dialog('close');
        this.reset();
    },

    getAttributes: function(){
        return {
            title: this.$('form [name=title]').val(),
            body: this.$('form [name=body]').val()
        }
    },

    reset: function(){
        this.$('input, textarea').val('');
    }
});

var NoteListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){

        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll');

        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(note){
        var view = new NoteListItemView({model: note});
        $(this.el).append(view.render().el);

        if(this.el.hasClass('ui-listview')){
            $(this.el).listview('refresh');
        }
    },

    addAll: function(){
        $(this.el).empty();
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    }
});

var NoteListItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'LI',
    template: _.template($('#note-list-item-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render')
        this.model.bind('change', this.render)
    },

    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template({ note: this.model }))
        return this;
    }
});

var NoteDetailView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "DIV",
    template: _.template($('#note-detail-template').html()),

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');

        $(this.el).attr({
            'data-role': 'page',
            'id': "note_" + this.model.id
        });

        this.model.bind('change', this.render);
    },

    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html(this.template({note: this.model}));
        return this;
    }
});

var NoteDetailList = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#note-detail-list'),

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'addOne', 'addAll', 'render');

        this.collection.bind('add', this.addOne);
        this.collection.bind('reset', this.addAll);

        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    addOne: function(note){
        var view = new NoteDetailView({model: note});

        $(this.el).append(view.render().el);

        if($.mobile){
            $.mobile.initializePage();
        }
    },

    addAll: function(){
        $(this.el).empty();
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    }
});

App.collections.all_notes = new NoteList()

App.views.new_form = new NewFormView({
    el: $('#new')
});

App.views.list_alphabetical = new NoteListView({
    el: $('#all_notes'),
    collection: App.collections.all_notes
})

App.views.notes = new NoteDetailList({
    collection: App.collections.all_notes
})

return App;
})()
```

**UPDATE:**

After digging through this a little more I have some more details on this error. The code is generating the dynamically created pages correctly they just can't be reached using the links in the listview. The links are referencing the hash with the ID of the DIV that I am trying to reach. The DIV has both data-role=page and data-url=#ID. These same pages can be reached using the following code via the console in Chrome and Firefox.

```
$.mobile.changePage($('#DIV ID'))
```

This works fine and the page is formatted correctly. According to the JQM documentation there was an issue where the links would not work if they were missing the data-url attribute but it was supposedly fixed in the JQM 1.0 release.

Comment: hey, I have the same issue running backbone with jquery mobile. have you found the solution?

Comment: Working through the tutorial at I worked through the tutorial at http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/ got me up and running with a simple backbone/JQM app.  Worth a look for anyone else who has gone down this route